# ctransformers module is not installed error in text-generation-webui

Tags: artificial-intelligence, llama, ctransformers

show error that **ctransformers** is not install in **text-generation-ui** but it is really has been installed in **window terminal** when i type **pip show ctransformers** . How I can solve this error. Really, I want to test llama2 Ai model with [text-generation-webui](https://github.com/oobabooga/text-generation-webui)

Error :

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\text-generation-webui\modules\ui_model_menu.py", line 210, in load_model_wrapper

shared.model, shared.tokenizer = load_model(shared.model_name, loader)

```
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\text-generation-webui\modules\models.py", line 85, in load_model

output = load_func_maploader

```
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\text-generation-webui\modules\models.py", line 272, in ctransformers_loader

from modules.ctransformers_model import CtransformersModel
File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\text-generation-webui\modules\ctransformers_model.py", line 1, in

from ctransformers import AutoConfig, AutoModelForCausalLM
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ctransformers'

I want made Ai project to test llama2 model with text-generatioin-webui

Answer (score 0):

I got similar errors when running start_macos.sh. After that, I run: python server.py, this issue was solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).